# Go revel tutorial で undefined: sql

Tags: go

## 環境

- macOS High Sierra
- sqliteではなく、mysql
- gorpではなく、gorm

参考: [Go言語フレームワークRevelとPaizaCloudを使って10分でWebサービスを作る方法 - paiza開発日誌](https://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/23/paizacloud_golang_revel)

booking tutorialの途中でエラーが出ました。
https://github.com/revel/examples/tree/master/booking

```
ERROR 18:33:28 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/gorm.go:31): undefined: sql"
```

## 経緯

controllers/app.goでgetUser を定義しようとしたら怒られました。
まず手始めに、Txnが定義されていないと言われたので、（以下）

```
ERROR 18:18:26 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/app.go:26): c.Txn undefined (type Application has no field or method Txn)"
```

`controllers/gorm.go` に

```
type Transactional struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *sql.Tx
}
```

を記述（あっているかわかりません。。。。）
これで、Txnを定義したと思ったら
一番上のエラーが出てきました。

sqlが見当たりませんと言われました。
Txn *sql.Txこの部分ですね。
どこかに、sqlの定義文が必要なのか、それともpackageをimportする必要があるのか？
それとも、他に原因があるのか？

## controllers/gorm.go

```
package controllers

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "booking/app/models"
    "log"
    )


type Transactional struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *gorm.Tx
}

var DB *gorm.DB

//dbの設定
func InitDB() {
    dbInfo, _ := revel.Config.String("db.info")
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dbInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("Failed gorm.Open: %v\n", err)
    }

    db.DB()
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Booking{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Hotel{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})

    DB = db
}
```

## controllers/app.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "booking/app/models"
    "booking/app/routes"
)

type Application struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c Application) Index() revel.Result {
    if c.connected() != nil {
        return c.Redirect(routes.Hotels.Index())
    }
    c.Flash.Error("Please log in first")
    return c.Render()
}

func (c Application) connected() *models.User {
    if c.ViewArgs["user"] != nil {
        return c.ViewArgs["user"].(*models.User)
    }
    if username, ok := c.Session["user"]; ok {
        return c.getUser(username.(string))
    }

    return nil
}

func (c Application) getUser(username string) (user *models.User) {
    user = &models.User{}
    _,  err := c.Session.GetInto("fulluser", user, false)
    if user.Username == username {
        return user
    }

    err = c.Txn.SelectOne(user, c.Db.SqlStatementBuilder.Select("*").From("User").Where("Username=?", username))
    if err != nil {
        if err != sql.ErrNoRows {
            //c.Txn.Select(user, c.Db.SqlStatementBuilder.Select("*").From("User").Limit(1))
            count, _ := c.Txn.SelectInt(c.Db.SqlStatementBuilder.Select("count(*)").From("User"))
            c.Log.Error("Failed to find user", "user", username, "error",err, "count", count)
        }
        return nil
    }
    c.Session["fulluser"] = user
    return
}

func (c Application) Register() revel.Result {
    return c.Render()
}
```

全体のコードが必要なら挙げます。
このTxnメソッドが邪魔なんだと思っています。
これは、gorpのメソッドなので、gormでは使用できないのではないか？とも思っています。
では、gormではどのようにすれば動くのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

多分ですけど、 sql パッケージを import する必要があると思います。

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/

```
import "database/sql"
```

すると解決しませんか？

Comment: import (
 "github.com/revel/revel"
 "booking/app/models"
 "booking/app/routes"
 "database/sql"
)
controllers/app.goに記述しました。エラーは変化しませんでした。。